# How can I call generic method unknowing instance object type

Tags: c#, generics, object, instance

With this code:

```
World w = new World();
var data = GetData<World>(w);
```

If I get `w` with reflection and this can be of type `World`, `Ambient`, `Domention`, etc.

How can I get `GetData` ???

I only have the instance object:

```
var data = GetData<???>(w);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var type = <The type where GetData method is defined>;

var genericType = typeof(w);

var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetData");

var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericType);

//instance or null : if the class where GetData is defined is static, you can put null : else you need an instance of this class.
var data = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(<instance or null>, new[]{w});
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to write  section. C# implicity decides the type of the parameter in a generic method if type is not declared; just go with:

```
var data = GetData(w);
```

Here is a sample;

```
public interface IM
{

}

public class M : IM
{
}

public class N : IM
{

}

public class SomeGenericClass 
{
    public T GetData<T>(T instance) where T : IM
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And you may call it like;

```
IM a = new M();
SomeGenericClass s = new SomeGenericClass();
s.GetData(a);
```